# Why can't it "combine with previous declaration specifier"

Tags: c++, c++11

I have some code that I am compiling for an embedded platform.  When I attempt to run a Clang-based tool against the code I get some errors.

I have narrowed down the code that generates the errors to the following:

```
typedef int _GCC_ATTR_ALIGN_8t __attribute__((__mode__(__QI__)));
typedef _GCC_ATTR_ALIGN_8t _Int8t __attribute__((__aligned__(1)));
typedef _Int8t _Intleast8t;
typedef _Int8t _Intfast8t;
typedef _Int8t _int8;
typedef _Int8t int8_t;
```

The output from running clang 3.8.0 against the code is:

```
x.cpp:5:16: error: cannot combine with previous 'type-name' declaration
      specifier
typedef _Int8t _int8;
               ^
x.cpp:5:1: warning: typedef requires a name [-Wmissing-declarations]
typedef _Int8t _int8;
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 warning and 1 error generated.
```

Why does it have the issue only on the _int8 typedef and not the other typedefs?  Also, what does the error mean?

Comment: `_int8` is probably defined to be some type somewhere already. I can't reproduce this on wandbox.

Comment: I built Clang 3.8.0 on Windows 10 using Visual Studio 2015.  I compiled it using `clang.exe x.cpp`.

Comment: As a side note identifiers starting with an underscore followed by a capital letter are reserved by the implementation. Unless the code in question is provided by the compiler/vendor it's incorrect. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/228797/845568 for more information.

Comment: Ah, OK, reproduced with `-fms-extensions`; in that mode it treats `_int8` as a keyword, equivalent to `char`.

Comment: That makes sense.  I added `-fno-ms-extensions` and it fixed it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Clang on Windows has `-fms-extensions` on by default, and in that mode [`_int8` is a keyword equivalent to `char`](http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/cfe-commits/Week-of-Mon-20140818/113163.html), because that's apparently what MSVC does.

Disable it with `-fno-ms-extensions`.